# Check if value is one of a given number of values - set vs. tuple vs. list

Tags: python

I have a `value` and want to check if that value is (for example) either `'5'`, `'test'` or `'#+*'`.
As far as I can tell I have a couple of options:

```
 value in ['5', 'test', '#+*']  # list
 value in ('5', 'test', '#+*')  # tuple
 value in {'5', 'test', '#+*'}  # set
```

Are those three statements equivalent or is there *some* difference?

---

*I am not really concerned about performance since the check will always compare against < 10 elements.*

Comment: probably the "right" way is to do that via set and it's more logical making sure container has no duplicates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a difference. First, the mutable data structures `list` and `set` will be larger in size, since they are growable and need to have associated overhead with them. `tuple` is immutable, and thus smaller in memory.

Second, checking for membership in a `tuple` or `list` is an O(N) operation, that is, it depends on the size of the data structure, since it must iterate from start to either the desired element or the end of the structure, whichever comes first. The `set` doesn't need to do this, since it's checking a hash and the lookup doesn't depend on the size of the `set`.

The pythonic way? It depends. If you are doing this test in a loop, then a `set` would make more sense since the time difference even for a small number of elements is noticable:

```py
❰mm92400❙~❱✔≻ python -m timeit -s 'x = list(range(9))' '8 in x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0979 usec per loop
❰mm92400❙~❱✔≻ python -m timeit -s 'x = tuple(range(9))' '8 in x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0968 usec per loop
❰mm92400❙~❱✔≻ python -m timeit -s 'x = set(range(9))' '8 in x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0278 usec per loop
```

Otherwise, for just a one-off, a `tuple` is smaller in memory, so I might go that route

Comment: Hello! It is perhaps worth mentioning that on my system the bytecode generated by `def f(): "z" in {"a", ..., "z"}` is `... LOAD_CONST               2 (frozenset({Ellipsis, 'z', 'a'})) ...` - meaning both that (1) Python actually does statically infer that this set is a completely literal expression, so it doesn't have to construct it every time, and (2) it infers that it can therefore make it an immutable `frozenset`. You can observe an analogous effect with lists and tuples.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Interesting! I didn't think to examine the bytecode at all, so in this case, is the memory overhead almost entirely eliminated?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen using `dis` on python 3.6, I don't see the `frozenset` optimization. I've tested against a few variations on membership checking, in loops, single line, etc. Could be platform dependent, I'm on macOS using HighSierra

Comment: Hmm you know I thought that it would, but upon further inspection with `sys.getsizeof`, it seems that frozensets are consistently exactly the same size as sets. But it means that in future a Python implementation theoretically *could* make this optimisation : )

Comment: I'm using 3.8.0 on a week-old arch linux, which is probably quite bleeding edge. How interesting! Of course none of this is of much consequence anyway

Comment: Still cool to note, I agree that this optimization could be quite nice in the future

Comment: @C.Nivs I checked the collections used in the `value in <collectionliteral>` tests. We can't assign the collections to variables, because then the optimizations wouldn't be done, but we can find the collections via `gc.get_objects()`. The tuple was of course a tuple, 64 bytes. The list was optimized into a tuple, also 64 bytes. The set was turned into a frozenset, 216 bytes. Most interestingly, I find **two** separate frozenset objects for that set. Weird.

Comment: [Code for my previous comment](https://tio.run/##XZDbSsQwEIbv8xQDe5FEgzeLB4S@hXgjUmo72UZiUjOpsCs@e520C9vtXE3@fHP6h2PuY9g/DWma3NcQU4ZDa4COJETrGyJ4bfyIzwI4OrRQ131DfV0rQm/1opdImMcUoHwqmZGy1Ksa/D5XGIi5x7QqtDFB/PgEF3jy3QFzzS9sM6kVVMJZcOQC5Sa0qBgyoLyjbCCPg0deGjm3KZ4wcKo1NKEDj6GwGqoK9rMid7c3soxj@XoCx5BcyEtz9qCsQ@6E0c49DLhuTrS45vXWhpc0ohA/xTqoFgsZOgs8@k3eSwOLT2bZ6B1gB@WeC6Xkw5bShZrvvWC/8nGL/RWMTZimfw).

Answer (score 2):

Since performance is of no issue, you *can* employ any of these approaches.

Although the idiomatic way would be to use set, since checking for membership is one of the primary reasons it exists in the first place.